# Why does the text move when click in mat-tab-group

Tags: angular

Please look at my situation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiguO.gif)

Here is my html

```
<mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab label="mat-tab-label">
  contents
</mat-tab>
<mat-tab label="mat-tab-label_0"> 
  contents
</mat-tab>
```

my scss

```
.mat-tab-label{
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 413px;
    height: 55px;}
.mat-tab-label:first-child{
    background-image: url(./img/icon01.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 30% 50%;
}
.mat-tab-label:last-child{
    background-image: url(./img/icon02.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 27% 50%;
}
```

The label moves every time you click.
I want to fix this.

Comment: its a css animation issue not angular. post more styles. what is the active class

Comment: I used the one provided by an angle material. So there is no css about animation.
Here is my .ts


 `import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic use of the tab group
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'tab-group-basic-example',
  templateUrl: 'tab-group-basic-example.html',
})
export class TabGroupBasicExample {}`

Answer (score 2):

This is managed by the pre-built themes css under .mat-ripple-element.  In the case of not utilizing one of those themes, the following rule is required in the css/scss:

```css
:host ::ng-deep .mat-ripple-element {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Note that the use of `:host ::ng-deep` as a means of styling elements in the shadow DOM is deprecated.  To date, I'm not aware of an alternative and it seems there remains reluctant acceptance of its use at the time of writing this.

Comment: "This is managed by the pre-built themes". These words saved my time. Actually i removed this `css` file from `angular.json` and was trying to resolve many issues. but after reading these words, i added the pre-built theme css file again and everything is working properly. Thanks a lot man :)